# selecting a cell in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

So I have a macro to clear some cells `A2-A250` but I want to return to cell `A1` once I have finished

```
Sub reset
Dim oActiveSheet As Variant
Dim oCellRangeByName As Variant

oActiveSheet = ThisComponent.getCurrentController().getActiveSheet()

oCellRangeByName = oActiveSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1:A250")

oCellRangeByName.clearContents(7)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

To move to a cell, select it:

```vb
oRange = oActiveSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1")
ThisComponent.getCurrentController().Select(oRange)
```

Section 6.5.3 of [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) discusses how to select a cell with or without the outline.  Add this code to unhighlight the cell:

```vb
oRanges = ThisComponent.createInstance("com.sun.star.sheet.SheetCellRanges")
ThisComponent.getCurrentController().Select(oRanges)
```